# Moving apps to SD: is there any difference between the function in Settings and the apps offered in the Google Play store?

Tags: app2sd, application-manager, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I noticed several apps in the Google Play store featuring the ability to move apps to the SD card. My Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 has an application manager under Settings, and this application manager already provides the ability to move apps to the SD card.

Without rooting my phone, is the included application manager doing the same thing as the apps in the store? Or is there something more the other apps can offer?

I ask because of a few problematic apps that take up a lot of device storage, even after telling them to move to the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

No they both use the same method to move it over. And if you did desist to root your phone, they could move over the ones that aren't allowed to be moved over, but that may cause them to break.